# PPS Integration with chrony

Tags: time, synchronization, time-synchronization, chrony

I am trying to get chrony to ingest a PPS signal to compare against just an NTP server. The PPS signal is recognized when I do ppswatch and ppstest, but when I do chronyc sources, the LastRX field occasionally goes up to 20+ while the NTP server stays around 0-1.

I believe the PPS should be the same since the rate is one pulse per second.

Is there something that could be causing my linux system or chrony to throw out samples? My PPS is 20us wide and about 5V (going into the DCD line).

my /etc/chrony.conf file is essentially like this

```
server <insert ip> minpoll -6 maxpoll -6
refclock PPS /dev/pps2 poll # prefer trust refid NTPS
//where # is from  -6 to 6. I've tried 0 through -6 to no success
```

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!